# What's the difference between is_null($var) and ($var === null)?

Tags: php

Is there any difference between this...

```
if (is_null($var)) {
    do_something();
}
```

and this?

```
if ($var === null) {
    do_something();
}
```

Which form is better when checking whether or not a variable contains null? Are there any edge cases I should be aware of? (I initialize all my variables, so nonexistent variables are not a problem.)

Comment: You would think the `===` operator would be faster since it's not an explicit function... but I've been surprised once or twice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Provided the variable is initialized (which you did indicate - though I'm not 100% sure if this matters in this context or not. Both solutions might throw a warning if the variable wasn't defined), they are functionally the same. I presume `===` would be marginally faster though as it removes the overhead of a function call.

It really depends on how you look at your condition.

`===` is for a strict data comparison. NULL has only one 'value', so this works for comparing against NULL (which is a PHP constant of the null 'value')

`is_null` is checking that the variable is of the NULL data type.

It's up to you which you choose, really.

Comment: Thanks for explaining compare-by-value vs. compare-by-type.

Comment: I prefer the `is_null` variant, because it is easy to accidentally use `== null` instead of `=== null`.  Since `== null` is the same as `empty` (see other answer), this introduces greater potential for programmer (especially junior and mid-level) error than a simple and readable `is_null`.

Answer (score 125):

`empty()` and `isset()` do not trigger a PHP  warning if their parameter is an undefined variable.
In most cases, such a warning is desirable to pinpoint the bugs. So only use the functions if you believe your variable can be legitimately undefined. It normally happens with an array index.

`✅` is `true`

`❌` is `false`

```php
        |  isset   | is_null | === null | == null | empty   |
|-------|----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|
| unset |    ❌   |    ✅   |    ✅    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
|  null |    ❌   |    ✅   |    ✅    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
|  true |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ❌  |    ❌   |
| false |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
|     0 |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
|     1 |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ❌  |    ❌   |
|    \0 |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ❌  |    ❌   |
|    "" |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
|    [] |    ✅   |    ❌   |    ❌    |    ✅  |    ✅   |
```

#### Summary:♦️

- `empty` is equivalent to `== null`
- `is_null` is equivalent to `=== null`
- `isset` is inverse of `is_null` and `=== null`

Comment: I really love this table.

Comment: it might make the table slightly more clear to have the first column  named `$v` to represent some generic variable, and then the others `isset($v)`, `is_null($v)`, `$v===null` and so on

Comment: @Brandin Thanks for the suggestion. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: @PHPst, Actually this **doesn't answer the question asked**: What's the difference between `is_null` vs `=== null`.

Comment: `isset` will not complain about an undefined variable, it will return false. Using `is_null` or `=== null` will result in a notice.

Comment: The misaligned columns in this table are causing me a lot of stress.

Answer (score 20):

Both are exactly same, I use `is_null` because it makes my code more readable

Comment: and while === may be faster at first, PHP optimiser should remedy that.

Comment: I feel `is_null` is actually less clear. While it may read nicely,  `$v === null` leaves no doubt that the comparison is done with strict semantics, but with `is_null($v)`, some coders will wonder if it uses `===` or `==` semantics.

Comment: @goat, ish1301, Also, `is_null` could be [removed or redefined](http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php) entirely, whereas `=== null` will always work.

Comment: @Pacerier while your example is interesting the likelihood of someone installing the runkit pecl package, then setting it up to allow removing built in functions and then removing is_null, of all things, without replacing it with something is very close to nil, or null if you prefer. The only scenario I can think of where a person would want to remove is_null, is if they wanted to change the behavior of the null comparison globally. For example; returning false instead of true for unset; In this case it would actually only be possible if the code was written with is_null to begin with.

Comment: They are not exactly the same, one is a function with call back option, the other is a straight comparison on a value

Answer (score 7):

If it seems redundant for php to have so many is_foo() type functions, when you can just use a standard comparison operators, consider programatically called functions.

```
$arrayOfNullValues = array_filter($myArray, 'is_null');
```

Comment: `$arrayWithoutNullValues` would store an array that has *only* `null` values, then.

Answer (score 6):

I've just run a quick benchmark, testing a million iterations of each. `is_null` took 8 seconds to complete; `=== null` took 1.

So a call to `is_null` is 0.000007s slower than a call to `===` on my computer.

I'd find something more useful to optimise.

---

My code:

```
<?php

$start = time();
$var = null;

for ($i = 1000000; $i--; ) {
    is_null($var);
}

echo time() - $start;

$start = time();

for ($i = 1000000; $i--; ) {
    $var === null;
}

echo time() - $start;
```

Comment: Interestingly, PHP/7 seems to have addressed this and performance is now  almost identical; in fact, `is_null()` is slightly faster in my computer under 7.1.9 Win32.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I noticed the same thing. The difference is negligible between the two functions. (is_null: 0.54486592610677, === null: 0.7440135592506) at 10,000 operations. The test was ran 30 times, and these numbers are the average.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the built in PHP function over the operator comparison every time.

Comment: Care to update your answer to cite some logical or technical reasons? As it stands it's simply an opinion

Answer (score 1):

One thing people often forget to mention in this discussion is that if you are all about strict type checking, `is_null` will help you to never make a typo in your comparison operators (== vs ===).

Answer (score 0):

`is_null($var)` is about 14 times slower than `$var===null`... 37.8 ms vs. 2.6 ms.

But actually I don't know why.

Comment: Because it's a function and it has overhead (e.g. setting up the callback etc). However in PHP7 it's about the same (reports show the function is actually marginally faster)