# is_null($x) vs $x === null in PHP

Tags: php, isnull

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between is_null($var) and ($var === null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662588/whats-the-difference-between-is-nullvar-and-var-null)

PHP has two (that I know of, and three if you count `isset()`) methods to determine if a value is null: `is_null()` and `=== null`.  I have heard, but not confirmed, that `=== null` is faster, but in a code review someone strongly suggested that I use `is_null()` instead as it is specifically designed for the null-evaluation purpose.  He also started talking about math or something.

Anyway, the fact that `is_null()` is apparently slower also leads me to believe that it's doing more than `=== null` does and is probably preferred.  Is there any reason to use one or the other?  Is one always preferred?  What about `isset()`?

As an addendum to possibly not get this question closed, what about `isset()` vs. `is_null()`?  It seems that all `isset()` will do is suppress the notice, so unless you actually *want* a notice for an undefined variable, any reason to use `is_null()` instead?  How about if you know the variable is initialized at the time?

Finally, is there any mathematical reason to prefer `is_null()` over `=== null`?  Something about null not being comparable?

Comment: Good question, but as far as I've learned, these kind of "improvements" are so minimal it does not matter what way you write it. Anyways, waiting for someone with competence to answer this, I'd like to know too.

Comment: Whoever voted to reopen should point out why this question is either not a duplicate of what it was closed with or why it should be allowed to co-exist. Also consider flagging it for merging.

Comment: Performance-wise: PHP 7 changes the old wisdom: ``===`` is no longer faster than ``is_null``.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

There is ***absolutely no*** difference in functionality between `is_null` and `=== null`.

The only difference is that `is_null` is a function and thus

1. is marginally slower (function call overhead)
2. can be used as a callback, e.g. `array_map('is_null', $array)`.

Personally, I use `null ===` whenever I can, as it is more consistent with `false ===` and `true ===` checks.

If you want, you can check the code: [`is_identical_function`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_operators.c#is_identical_function) (`===`) and [`php_is_type`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/type.c#php_is_type) (`is_null`) do the same thing for the `IS_NULL` case.

---

The related `isset()` language construct checks whether the variable actually exists before doing the `null` check. So `isset($undefinedVar)` will not throw a notice.

Also note that `isset()` may sometimes return `true` even though the value is `null` - this is the case when it is used on an overloaded object, i.e. if the object defines an `offsetExists`/`__isset` method that returns `true` even if the offset is `null` (this is actually quite common, because people use `array_key_exists` in `offsetExists`/`__isset`).

Comment: Good point on the speed difference.

Comment: According to a comment in the documentation, `is_null()` is now marginally faster in PHP7 than `=== NULL` but the difference between the two is far smaller than that of previous versions and not worth worrying about.

Comment: Ive tested both using a for-loop with 100,000,000 iterations on PHP `7.4`. The difference is negligible. Just pick one and use it.

Comment: The **only real difference** between checking for null using `=== null` or `is_null()` is the point about callback functions mentioned above. Because `is_null()` exists, you don't have to make a closure/anonymous function and put `=== null` inside every time you want to e.g. `array_filter()` using a `null` check, you can just pass in `'is_null'` as the callback function. It exists to make code more readable, not to increase execution speed.

Answer (score 19):

As stated by others, there is a time difference between using `===` and `is_null()`. Did some quick testing and got these results:

```
<?php

//checking with ===
$a = array();
$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {
    if($a[$i] === null) {
         //do nothing
    }
}
echo 'Testing with === ', microtime(true) - $time, "\n";

//checking with is_null()
$time = microtime(true);
for($i=0;$i<10000;$i++) {
    if(is_null($a[$i])) {
         //do nothing
    }
}
echo 'Testing with is_null() ', microtime(true) - $time;
?>
```

Gives the results

> Testing with === 0.0090668201446533
>
> Testing with is_null() 0.013684034347534

[See the code in action](http://codepad.org/AJB1eFW1)

Comment: You're doing 10000 operations in a loop and the time difference turns out to be less than 5 milliseconds. It doesn't matter. It will never matter. Nobody trying to improve their application's performance has ever declared "curses, if only I could shave half a microsecond off this null check!", and nobody ever will.

Comment: @MarkAmery I am going for whatever performs better at same cost, and always will. Care less is worse than care more in a 50k+ files app.

Comment: I think the point here is there's no need to refactor if you've already used is_null, but there's no point in using it _from now on_, if you get my drift.

Comment: There are cases where simple operations are repeated a lot. E.g. a parser that looks at each character in a long file.

Comment: Program execution time tends to follow a Pareto distribution i.e. ~20% of the codebase is responsible for ~80% of the runtime (when its not 10/90 or even 1/99). So, ya, this kind of microoptimization won't usually buy you much.

Comment: @donquixote - FWIW, Mark Amery's point is that the difference here is so miniscule, that the cases where it would matter are really really rare.

Comment: The speed leverage was very low. But now in PHP 7.1 they both execute at the same speed.

Answer (score 6):

They all have their places, though only isset() will avoid undefined variable warnings:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump(is_null($a));
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in php shell code on line 1
bool(true)
php > var_dump($a === null);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in php shell code on line 1
bool(true)
php > var_dump(isset($a));
bool(false)
php >
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not able to say wether it's better to use `is_null` or `=== null`. But be aware when using `isset` on arrays.

```
$a = array('foo' => null);

var_dump(isset($a['foo'])); // false
var_dump(is_null($a['foo'])); // true
var_dump(array_key_exists('foo', $a)); // true
```

Comment: +1 for array_key_exists('foo', $a), the use is finding keys that are set to null because for some reason is_null($a['foo']) returns true for undefined properties AND null keys?????

Comment: What's the "beware"?  isset(nullValue) will always return `false`

Comment: I don't recall why I wrote that specifically, since it's long time ago. I assume because back then I had the assumption that it was common practice to check for existence of an array key using `isset`. I guess it's better to use `array_key_exists` in that case, but I'm also not working with PHP anymore since 10 years :)

Answer (score 5):

`===` and `is_null` is the same.

According to [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php#84161) `is_null` is only 250ns slower. I think because a function is slower than an operator.

Comment: On PHP 7.2.19 (and an i5-8265U), is_null is actually faster. But `null ===` is only 1 nanosecond slower. Don't bother with the difference.

Comment: For reference, ~1 ns is around 4 to 5 clock cycles at 3.9GHz. Given that Whiskey Lake seems to be able to retire 6 instructions per cycle, that's still up to 24 to 28 instructions. But that's wayyy beyond the detail of the underlying hardware that you have in PHP (which tends to be >10x-30x slower than C anyways).

Answer (score 4):

You need `isset()` if the variable is possibly not defined. It returns false when the variable is not defined or `=== null` (yes, it's *that* ugly). Only `isset()` and `empty()` do not raise an E_NOTICE if the variable or array element does not exist.

There is not really a difference between `is_null` and `=== null`. I think `===` is much nicer but when you e.g. need to use `call_user_func` for some dubious reason, you'd have to use `is_null`.

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) has a good discussion and experiments on `is_null, === null, isset`. Especially read the comment section.