# Checking if a variable is null

Tags: php, isset, isnull

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is_null($x) vs $x === null in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228837/is-nullx-vs-x-null-in-php)

In the following context `!== null`, `!is_null()` and `isset()` all produce the same result:

```
$foo = null;

function foo() {
    if ($this->foo !== null) {
        ...
    }
    if (!is_null($this->foo)) {
        ...
    }
    if (isset($this->foo)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Which one is the quickest and which would you recommend in that context?

Comment: in PHP5 you can't use isset() for variable only for http request, post or get

Comment: @Robuust What?  of course you can use it for any variable.  `$a = 5; if (isset($a)) { echo "a = {$a}"; }`

Comment: Regarding which is the quickest, [a comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php#83588) included benchmarks for each of the methods looping over 10M iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not sure that the variable exists, use `isset`.

Example:

```
$content = (isset($_POST['content'])) ? $_POST['content'] : null;
```

Otherwise, use strict comparison to null.

```
if ($content === null) { }
```

(Really, I'm just pushing my opinion on your with the strict comparison.  I just think it looks better than is_null, and it's probably an extremely small bit faster.)

Answer (score 1):

Use `isset` only if the variable *may not be set*. I.e. if you do not know whether the variable exists at this point or not. Since you do know that it should exist at this point, don't use `isset`.

The difference between `!== null` and `!is_null` is negligible and mostly depends on your preference. Personally, I like `!== null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->foo !== null) {
      //...
}
```

I prefer this condition.

Answer (score 0):

According to me

```
  if($this->foo!=""){
```

//...
}

this is the quickest one and produce the result quickly