# Check if array value isset and is null

Tags: php, arrays, isset, isnull

How to check if array variable

```
$a = array('a'=>1, 'c'=>null);
```

is set and is null.

```
function check($array, $key)
{
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        if (is_null($array[$key])) {
            echo $key . ' is null';
        }
        echo $key . ' is set';
    }
}

check($a, 'a');
check($a, 'b');
check($a, 'c');
```

Is it possible in PHP to have function which will check if $a['c'] is null and if $a['b'] exist without "PHP Notice: ..." errors?

Comment: I don't get any notice warnings with your code.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) instead of `isset()`, because `isset()` will return `false` if the variable is `null`, whereas `array_key_exists()` just checks if the key exists in the array:

```
function check($array, $key)
{
    if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
        if (is_null($array[$key])) {
            echo $key . ' is null';
        } else {
            echo $key . ' is set';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pulzarraider why did you replace `is_null()` with `===`?

Comment: Because it's faster.

Comment: @pulzarraider - Any evidence to back up that claim? Because [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228837/is-nullx-vs-x-null-in-php) and [this post](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php#84161) seems to heavily disagree with you, saving nanoseconds at best and making your edit a superfluous micro-optimization.

Comment: Yes, it's microoptimization, but why not make your function the fastest as it can be? Isset() is a bit slower because it's function call.

Answer (score -2):

You may pass it by reference:

```
function check(&$array, $key)
{
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        if (is_null($array[$key])) {
            echo $key . ' is null';
        }
        echo $key . ' is set';
    }
}

check($a, 'a');
check($a, 'b');
check($a, 'c');
```

SHould give no notice

But `isset` will return `false` on null values. You may try `array_key_exists` instead

Comment: The original code also doesn't give a notice. Passing by reference is unnecessary.

Comment: @nickb, you post answer while I was checking if things I remember were right:)

Comment: It is what I wanted. Because of isset returning false on null I will do it like this: if(!isset($array[$key]) && is_null($array[$key])) which equals true if $array[$key] is null.

Comment: @BartekKosa your implementation is flawed. It will also return true and notice for keys that don't exists.

Comment: My final version would be if(is_null(...){ catch all nulls}elseif(isset(...)){ catch all set variables}. But the most important trick is passing an array by reference to get rid of "Notice".

Comment: Have you tested this? I believe isset() always returns false for null values even if they "exist" thus the is_null() will never be reached. The problem from the OP question remains.