# What is the point of is_null()?

Tags: php, error-reporting, notice

My question is regarding the use of `is_null()`.

I've read other questions that discuss [is_null($x) versus null === $x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228837/is-nullx-vs-x-null-in-php), but I am more concerned with why there is an `is_null()` function at all?

A few tests to explain my thinking:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
error_reporting(-1);

$test = 'Hello, World!';
$test2 = null;
$test3 = '';

var_dump(is_null($test));
var_dump(null === $test);
var_dump(isset($test));

var_dump(is_null($test2));
var_dump(null === $test2);
var_dump(isset($test2));

var_dump(is_null($test3));
var_dump(null === $test3);
var_dump(isset($test3));

var_dump(is_null($test4));
var_dump(null === $test4);
var_dump(isset($test4));
```

which will produce the following output:

```
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)

Notice: Undefined variable: test4 in C:\home\ombrelle.co.uk\templates_core\test.php on line 22
bool(true)

Notice: Undefined variable: test4 in C:\home\ombrelle.co.uk\templates_core\test.php on line 23
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

As you can see, when using the `is_null()` function or comparison method it will throw a notice, so you're forced to use `isset()` instead. So the only way to never see a notice using these methods is when it's not `null`?

Also consider the following:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
error_reporting(-1);

var_dump((is_null($test1)) ? 'test1' : $test);
var_dump((null == $test2) ? 'test2' : $test);
var_dump((isset($test3)) ? 'test3' : $test);
```

giving the following output:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: test1 in C:\home\ombrelle.co.uk\templates_core\test.php on line 6
string(5) "test1"

Notice: Undefined variable: test2 in C:\home\ombrelle.co.uk\templates_core\test.php on line 7
string(5) "test2"

Notice: Undefined variable: test in C:\home\ombrelle.co.uk\templates_core\test.php on line 8
NULL
```

Here in a ternary statement, the aforementioned work, still with notices, however the `isset()` method now *doesn't* work at all. How would one go about this properly, without showing notices?

After all that, am I just to accept that notices are pointless and shouldn't be sent to my error log, or are there any other caveats I should consider?

We are currently cleaning an old system of lots of errors - we don't want to miss any, but also there's no point creating more errors for ourselves either. Any links to authoritative reading on the matter are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you do not distinguish variable which has `null` value and variable that is not defined. These are to different things.

Comment: In other words: is_null is a function, just like is_bool, is_int, is_<whatever>. Only since the null-type has only 1 possible value, it is in practice equal to === null. It's just like is_bool is equal to ($var === true or $var === false). A non-existant variable in a comparison is treated as a variable with no value (ie. null) and hence returns true on null === $undefined. However, when passing no-variable as an argument to a function, the function recieves nothing, while it expects at least something, and thus returns a notice.

Comment: I think what confused me here was that `$something = null; var_dump(isset($something));` will output `false`. It's not *actually* throwing an error when using `is_null` though, if it's set to `null`. Weird. Or am I being silly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_null()` Finds whether the variable is NULL

You really need `isset()` which determines if a variable is set and is not NULL. Returns `TRUE` if variable exists and has value other than `NULL`, otherwise `FALSE`.

For instance,

```
$something = null; then isset($something) returns false
$something = 'some value'; then isset($something) returns true
```

Comment: As I mentioned in reply to @Tularis above, when I put `$something = null; var_dump(isset($something));`, it will return `false`. So unless I **knew** that it was really set (i.e. not at code time) I couldn't use `is_null`, right?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can think of (except for being way slower - like the answer in the linked answer you posted), is that [`is_null`](http://www.php.net/is_null) allows use of the [horrible `@` operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    var_dump($foo === null); //Notice
    var_dump(@is_null($foo)); //No notice
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/tlHMnktx)

That said, if you aren't sure if a variable exists you should use `isset` and not `is_null`.

On top of that, you might be interested in [Best way to test for a variable's existence in PHP; isset() is clearly broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418066/best-way-to-test-for-a-variables-existence-in-php-isset-is-clearly-broken)

Comment: `is_null` is a way to check the `type` of the variable. `=== null` checks the `type` and the `value`. Since a `null type` has only a single possible value, those two are in practice the same. However, is_null exists to keep consistency in the language (ie. as a parallel to `is_bool`, `is_int`, `is_object`, `is_array`, etc.)