# is_null vs ===null

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between is_null($var) and ($var === null)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662588/whats-the-difference-between-is-nullvar-and-var-null)

Is there any difference between following code:

```
if(is_null($x)) { ...
```

and

```
if($x===null) { ...
```

Comment: Is the documentation not enough? [Read the comments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) and [Google seems to have plenty of results about this - you might want to consider `===` as well!](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/php-is_null-vs-null/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662588/whats-the-difference-between-is-nullvar-and-var-null

Comment: this question shouldnt be upvoted uselessly. Many exact duplicates already exist

Answer (score 2):

Yes. `==` is a loose comparison, meaning a lot more than just `NULL` will result in `true` in the second version. See the [type comparison tables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Comment: NULL does not mean true/false, it means unkown value, so be careful when using it !