# difference between is_null "== NULL" and "=== NULL" in PHP

Tags: php, null, identity, equality

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php == vs === operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator)

i have the following code fragment and it doesn't make sense to me why would NULL be evaluated in 3 different ways. Consider the variable `$uploaded_filenames_array` as UNKNOWN - we don't know whether it's still an array or a NULL. That's what we are trying to check.

```
//-----------------------------------------------
if (is_null($uploaded_filenames_array)){
    echo "is_null";
}
else{
    echo "is_NOT_null";
}
//-----------------------------------------------
if ($uploaded_filenames_array == NULL){
    echo "NULL stuff";
}
else{
    echo "not NULL stuff";
}
//-----------------------------------------------
if ($uploaded_filenames_array === NULL){
    echo "NULL identity";
}
else{
    echo "not NULL identity";
}
//-----------------------------------------------
```

i am getting the following response:

```
is_NOT_null 
NULL stuff 
not NULL identity
```

can somebody help to understand what is the programmatic difference between these 3 ways of checking NULL?

Comment: is_null is equivalent to "===".

Comment: how is this question an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589549/php-vs-operator? That question doesn't talk about is_null.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`is_null($a)` is same as `$a === null`.

(`$a === null` is bit faster than `is_null($a)` for saving one function call, but it doesn't matter, just choose the style you like.)

For the difference of `===` and `==`, read [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

`$a === null` be true only if `$a` is `null`.

But for `==`, the below also returns `true`.

```
null == false
null == 0
null == array()
null == ""
```

Comment: +1 for editing it out nicely with extra information :)

Comment: -1 for editing it out nicely with extra information not relevant to the question :)

Comment: @salathe So what is the irrelevant part ? :)

Comment: "only if"?  What about unset values? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15607428/543738

Answer (score 3):

You should read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php. Also no need to use `is_null` function to check only on `NULL`. `===` is faster...

Answer (score 1):

`==` checks if the *value* is equal e.g.:

```
>> "123" == 123
<< true
```

`===` checks if the **value & type** are equal e.g.:

```
>> "123" === 123
<< false
```

Comment: so `is_null` is identical to `===`?

Comment: No, `is_null` checks if the value provided is not `null`, so: `function is_null($value) { return $value === null; }`

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator tests for the same value and the same TYPE. An empty string might evaluate to null, but it is not of the `null` type - hence this fails.

The `==` operator basically checks to see if they are pretty much the same - by that, do the evaluate to the same value. Being empty, this will evaluate to null, hence this fails.

The `is_null` function does a fairly thorough check - much more like the `===` operator.